# C# regex filters

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex filter: `<+>|\P{L}`

Numbers and HTML tags are deleted.

My problem is that spaces are also deleted and I don't want spaces to be deleted.

For example, I need to change this text "(0) Ship Out" to this "Ship Out".  Now it returns  "ShipOut".

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for a way to still match `\P{L}` (any character that is not a Unicode letter) and still be able to not match a space.

Just use a reverse shorthand class `\p{L}` in a negated character class `[^\p{L}\s]`.

No idea if `<+>` is working for you, you might be looking for `<[^<]*>`.

So, my suggestion is

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"<[^<]*>|[^\p{L}\s]", string.Empty).Trim();
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3E%7C%5B%5E%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cs%5D&i=%3Cb%3E(0)%20Ship%20Out%3C%2Fb%3E&r=)

[image]

`Trim()` will get rid of leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Nomi you were using `match` or `replace` earlier

Comment: Glad to be of help. One remark: if you are *parsing* HTML you'd better use some HTML parser instead of just removing tags with regex. This will save you lots of trouble. Have a lookt at [my answer describing how to get clean text from HTML document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385985/c-sharp-regular-expressions-get-second-number-not-first/31386196#31386196).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <+>|\P{L}|\P{Z}
```

You can use this filter for that.

[See demo.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bL%7d%7c%5cp%7bZ%7d&i=(0)+Ship+Out)

You can also use

```
\p{L}|(?<=\p{L})\p{Z}(?=\p{L})
```

If you want to preserve `space` between words only

Comment: This [will remove everything in the sample input](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%2b%3e%7c%5cP%7bL%7d%7c%5cP%7bZ%7d&i=%3cb%3e(0)+Ship+Out%3c%2fb%3e&r=).

Comment: @stribizhev OP probably is using a match instead of replace.As `p{L}` will match `Ship Out` too