# Return 100 characters from a string with html tags but ignoring the tag characters

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

Now I have a string that have html tags like

```
<div> <p> and <br>
```

And there is readable text too of course.. Now what I want to return is readable text **BUT** only 100 characters of it..
I have tried below options but it didn't help.

1. Regex to remove tags. (Left me with extra spaces or null spaces)
2. Substring (0, 100). (It read html tags as characters too of course)

**Note**: I cannot use javascript.

Below is my sample string ..

```
<div class="ExternalShit23429812"><p>This is a paragraoph.. </p><br><p>What</p><p>Yeah right</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>and Paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph yes yes yes</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p><p>More paragraph</p></div>
```

Comment: use mshtml and play with the elements

Comment: You should use Javascript or server side solution if you want to exact first 100 characters.

Comment: If you're using C#, use AngleSharp for a jquery-like interface: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp

Comment: What code have you written so far? What's you effort?

Comment: @Sunil All I could think of is to replace or remove the html tags from string and then count and minus characters. But however I cannot remove <p> tags, since I need to show it as it is formatted.

Comment: Isn't there anyway I could ignore the html tags in the string. and then count and minus the characters ?

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack and get the clean HTML text using [`public string getCleanHtml(string html)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    return HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31386196/3832970) and then just get the substring from 0 to 100.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have got an error 
`Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.6.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 1):

I never worked on C# but Below are the solutions for your problem in javascript and in Java. You can get an idea by looking these examples:

**JavaScript:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStringWithOutTags(id, length){
        var str = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        while(true){
            var start = str.indexOf("<");
            if(start < 0){
                break;
            }   
            var end = str.indexOf(">", start);
            var temp = str.substring(start, end+1);
            str = str.replace(temp, "");
        }
        var output = (str.length > 100) ? str.substring(0,100) : str;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = output; 
    }
    </script>
```

**Java:-**

```
public static String getStringWithOutTags(String str, int length){
    while(true){
        int start = str.indexOf("<");
        if(start < 0){
            break;
        }   
        int end = str.indexOf(">", start);
        String temp = str.substring(start, end+1);
        str = str.replace(temp, "");
    }
    return (str.length() > length) ? str.substring(0, length) : str;
}
```

Good Luck !!!

Comment: I tried your function, it does the same thing that I did with regex.

I am being returned with this
`This is a paragraoph.. What Yeah right Paragraphand Paragraph More paragraphMore paragraph More para`

And however, I still need <p> tags to show the text with formation.

Comment: do you need <p> in starting and </p> in end ?? or every <p> and </p> wherever came in string

Comment: Yes every <p> and </p> .. And also <br> .. but because of this, I cannot count the exact length of my characters in string. Since the tags are also being count with `.length`. i.e.. `<p>123</p><br><p>456</p><p>789</p> = 34 chars` .. when I want only 6 chars means `<p>123</p><br><p>456</p>` and not `<p>123`